# compare password stored in php session variable with new entered password using js

Tags: javascript, php, validation, authentication, login-script

How can I compare  new entered password with old password stored in php session variable.

I am using the following code. Result of this code is always "password entered is not correct" i.e if loop is not working when entering right password.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <div id="dom-target" style="display: none;">
        <?php 
            session_start();
            $oldPsassword=$_SESSION['storpass'];
            echo htmlspecialchars($oldPsassword);

        ?>
    </div>    
    <form name="myForm2" method ="post" action = "index-login.php" onsubmit="return PasswordMatch()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Old Password</label>
            <input type="password" name = "op" placeholder="old Password" id = "opass" class="form-control" >
        </div>
    </form>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
function PasswordMatch() {    
    var div = document.getElementById("dom-target");
    var oldPass =div.textContent;

    var oldPass1 =document.getElementById("op").value;

    if (oldPass1 == oldPass) {    
        alert("password entered is correct");     
    }
    else
    {
        alert("password entered is not correct");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: how debug stuff: "Q: why oldPass1 != oldPass?", "A: let's see what's inside: console.log(oldPass1, oldPass);"

Comment: You should never output the old password in your HTML page. You shouldn't even be storing it as plain text. Do this verification via ajax.

Comment: Have you tried it without the htmlspecialchars()? It looks like that is causing some encoding you may not want when comparing two passwords:http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlspecialchars.asp

Comment: As a side note have a look at the outputs of these two `$string = "<!?fgt?}@>";
echo $string."\n";
echo htmlspecialchars($string);` You will notice they are very different, this may cause you some issues going forward.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a debugging service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. The id of your input is `opass` not `op`. Change the `getElementById()` call.
2. The container `dom-target` has whitespace before and after the password which will cause it not to match. You can trim it to solve that

Add trim:

```
var oldPass = div.textContent.trim();
```

However, storing the old password in the HTML is insecure. Anyone can inspect the HTML to find the password. You should do the comparison on the server side instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have used wrong id for `oldpass1`

use this:

```
var oldPass1 =document.getElementById("opass").value;
```

as you have given opass id to the input field